# error:Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:0.9.11:dockerBuild dockerizing JHipster-Registry

Tags: java, jhipster, jhipster-registry

When I run this command:

```
mvn -e package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
```

in `jhipster-registry` standard project, to dockerize this application, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:0.9.11:dockerBuild (default-cli) on project jhipster-registry: Invalid image reference: JHipster Registry:5.0.0 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:0.9.11:dockerBuild (default-cli) on project jhipster-registry: Invalid image reference: JHipster Registry:5.0.0
```

The link suggested in Help1 is:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "generic error message".
My solution is:

```
docker system prune
```

This clean the docker images/container and the build docker images of registry gonna be ok.

Answer (score 1):

delete target file from you project, and then execute inside terminal this command `./mvnw` or `./mvnw install`
and after that try again with this command `mvn -e package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild` inside terminal also

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out from Docker Hub application, and then exexute the command again. It would work.

If this does not work. Go to "C:\Users<your_user_home_directory>.docker" path.

Just delete the credsStore property from the config.json file. You will find the config.json at your user-home directory.